# Make post request in Rails Admin authenticate_with block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rails-admin

I have Rails API mode using devise_token_auth and this problem concerns authentication in rails_admin.

In my rails_admin initializer, I want to do something like this:

```
config.authenticate_with do
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Sign in') do |username, password|
    app.post('/auth/sign_in', {'email' => username, 'password' => password})
  end
end
```

I can do `app.post('/auth/sign_in', {'email' => username, 'password' => password})` just fine from the rails console. but when running my app, I get an error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `app' for #\u003cRailsAdmin::MainController:
```

Comment: Couldnt this be better solved with devise basic auth? rails admin works with devise by default.

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-HTTP-Basic-Authentication

Comment: thanks for pointing me to devise basic auth I'll definitely check it out. Now, can you answer the question? "Make post request in Rails Admin authenticate_with block". I'd be happy to accept your answer after I wait a few more days for others to chime in.